# Coding character movements with animation per direction using the mouse in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 2d rpg game in unity, with an isometric tile setup or level.

I would like to code or connect the characters upward, right, left and diagonal animation movements using mouse button as the controls (like the Red Alert 2 game controls). These can easily be done using keyboard inputs. However, what I am trying to aim is to control the character by using the mouse click and make the animation follow it correctly. For example if I click in a diagonal location from the character, the character should follow it and it will also do the diagonal animation.

Comment: Hi Merk, Welcome to S.O. Your question might get a better response at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ which is specifically tailored for games development.

Comment: Hi! Thank you, how do I move this question to that area?

Comment: Just sign in / sign up, and post your question, as you did here. Questions gets a much better response if you include what you've tried and where you're struggling, rather than just asking "how do i do this" : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask